# Error: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in my PHP code

Tags: php, for-loop, nested-for-loop

I have limited knowledge of PHP. I am getting this error on this code in the forloop part.

`Trying to access array offset on value of type null on line ...`

I am seeing this in a local environment as well as online when I enabled debugging in a Wordpress project. I think is related to the nested forloop but I am not sure what the exact problem is.

The error is thrown on the line starting with the if condition after the try block. I have removed some of the code inside the if condition and replace them with `...` What am I missing in the forloop or variable declaration code?

```
public function render_element_css( $code, $id ){
        
        global $kc;
        
        $css_code = '';
        $css_any_code = '';
        $css_desktop_code = '';
        $pro_maps = array( 
            'margin' => array('margin-top','margin-right','margin-bottom','margin-left'), 
            'padding' => array('padding-top','padding-right','padding-bottom','padding-left'), 
            'border-radius' => array('border-top-left-radius','border-top-right-radius','border-bottom-right-radius','border-bottom-left-radius')
        );
            
        try{    
            $screens = json_decode( str_replace( '`', '"', $code ), true );
            if (is_array( $screens['kc-css']))
            {
                kc_screen_sort ($screens['kc-css']);

                foreach ($screens['kc-css'] as $screen => $groups)
                {
                ...
                    
                }
            
            }
            
        }catch( Exception $e ){
             echo "\n\n/*Caught exception: ",  $e->getMessage(), "*/\n\n";
        };
        
        return kc_images_filter($css_any_code.$css_code);
        
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the _full_ error message and point to the _exact_ line in the code it's thrown in. You should also remove all code that's not actually relevant. You've posted a lot here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show which line the error is indicating. If possible, also reduce the code to a [mre] - there's a lot to read through here, and you may find that by narrowing down the problem you discover the cause yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

This line:

```
$screens = json_decode( str_replace( '`', '"', $code ), true );
```

will make the json invalid before you're trying to decode it.

Imagine you have a string like this:

```
$json = '{"foo": "lorem `bar` ipsum"}';
```

If you run your current `str_replace()` on it before trying to decode the string, it will become:

```
$json = '{"foo": "lorem "bar" ipsum"}';
```

See the issues with the quotes? If you try to decode that using `json_decode()`, it will fail and return `null`, which means that `$screens['kc-css']` will throw the error message you're getting.

#### Solution

You need to escape the double quote with a backslash: `\"` if you want to use a literal double quote inside a double quoted string.

Change it to:

```
$screens = json_decode( str_replace( '`', '\"', $code ), true );
```

and it should work.

[Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/bBIBK)

Comment: Thanks for sharing but this issue has not been resolved

Comment: @Wacademy - Do you get the same error message on the same line, or do you get the same/or a new error somewhere else? I'm curious since you accepted this earlier saying that it _did_ solve the issue. You need to give us some actual info here, or we have no idea where to start.

Comment: The if condition is a long post. And I am still getting the error on the if condition line. Meanwhile I don't know if there are other part of the code where this issue also apply. I have another line of code like this ```}else if( $sel[0] == 'custom' ){
$css = trim( str_replace( array('"', "'", '[', ']'), array('', '', '', ''), $css ) ).'{{{end}}}';``` I don't know if it applies here

Comment: If this answer solved the original error you posted about, then you should accept it. If you get more errors in other parts of the code, that should be a new question where you post all the relevant code, info and errors related to _that_ error.  Otherwise you're just moving the goal post. I can't make any determination from the code you posted in your comment either way since it's completely lacking context.

Comment: I'll agree with you